# How to send ADA to Daedalus Mainnet wallet?

Tags: wallet, daedalus

I downloaded Daedalus Mainnet 4.0.5.  I created a wallet, but I don't see an address where I can send my ADA from an exchange.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the **Receive** tab to select an address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Wallet` icon and then `Receive` tab. Choose one of twenty addresses and click it. Now you're able to copy an address or scan a QR code to send your funds from exchange.

Besides, Cardano uses the [*EUTxO*](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/eutxo-explainer) accounting model on the mainnet. According to this, user-friendly Daedalus wallet automatically choose a new address to send change to it, if you send a part of funds back to exchange.